# Flask - SQLAlchemy - Add nullable=False column to existing table with data

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I'm trying to add a new `nullable=False` column to an existing table. But it won't create the column because there are existing rows and the field is `Null`.

It's a classic catch 22 :D.

here's my model column I added:

```py
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
```

here's the error I get

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) column "user_id" contains null values
```

I tried adding `, default=0` to the end of the attribute in the model hoping the migration would just set all existing row's column values to `0`, but this didn't have any effect.

I don't see any documentation around this seemingly common phenomenon so I thought I'd ask the experts. What am I missing?

Comment: I would amend migration file..add column in nullable form, update with what user_id should be if null, then set nullable false.

Answer (score 0):

A typical error message would be something like the following.

`sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) column "user_id" contains null values`

A workaround would be to set foreign key IDs to `0` for existing records, then treat them as `None` in your application code. The upgrade in the migration would look like this, where you have two tables `team` and `user`, and want to set a default value of `team_id` in the `user` record:

```python
    team = op.create_table(
        "team",
        sa.Column("id", sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
        sa.Column("name", sa.Text(), nullable=False),
        sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint("id", name=op.f("pk_team")),
    )
    op.bulk_insert(
        team,
        [
            {"id": 0, "name": "Not Set"},
            {"id": 1, "name": "Team 1"},
            # ...
            {"id": N, "name": "Team N"},
        ],
    )


    op.add_column(
        "user",
        sa.Column("team_id", sa.Integer(), nullable=False, server_default="0"),
    )
    op.alter_column("user", "team_id", server_default=None)
    op.create_foreign_key(
        op.f("fk_team_id_user"),
        "user",
        "team",
        ["team_id"],
        ["id"],
        onupdate="CASCADE",
        ondelete="CASCADE",
    )
```

I might have got the child and parent swapped around, but this should give y'all something to try.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem as you. Please see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16100442/10240279) from another thread. Essentially, the "default" argument in the Column definition is only used by the class instance. If you'd like to set a default that the migration can interpret, use the "server_default" argument with a SQL expression instead.